# mat-dialog remember previous data on next opening

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, dialog, modal-dialog

I use mat-dialog and encountered a problem related to keeping the data from previously opened window.

- When opening it to **add** a record, the field is empty.
- But, if I open it for **edit** and then open for **add** new record, it retains the data that is on the previously opened dialog.

So, I want to prevent this on the dialog close event, but I do not find a proper way to catch when dialog close except from the following one that I cannot use dur to some limitation of our dialog template.

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    this.dataService.onSelectCustomer.next([]); 
});
```

So, how to fix this problem by mat-dialog property or catching the close event? It would also be enough ***to fire an event when dialog is closed by clicking cancel or outside of the window***.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may encountered similar problem, I would like to share the solution that I just found now:

•  we are then creating an instance of MatDialogConfig, which will configure the dialog with a set of default behaviors

•  we are overriding a couple of those default behaviors. for example, we are setting disableClose to true, which means that the user will not be able to close the dialog just by clicking outside of it

•  we are also setting autoFocus to true, meaning that the focus will be set automatically on the first form field of the dialog

```
openDialog() {
  const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

  dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
  dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;

  dialogConfig.data = {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Angular For Beginners'
  };

  this.dialog.open(CourseDialogComponent, dialogConfig);
}
```